# how to access a file which is in other system using linux

Tags: linux, file, system

how to access a file which is located in another system using Linux?
using Linux commands how can we access a file which is stored in a different system?

Comment: How are the systems connected? Is the target system running a file sharing service that gives you access to the directory you need? If so, do you know the full path to the file?

Comment: Look for `scp`, `rsync`, [git](http://git-scm.com/), `ftp`, `curl`, `wget`, NFS but your question is not clear enough

Comment: USB memory stick maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share files between two system on linux ,you can using following methods:

- Transferring Files with NFS
- Sharing Files with Samba

**NFS implementation**

To configure the server, proceed as follows:

Prepare the system:

Open a shell, log in as root, and grant write permissions to all users:

mkdir /srv/nfs
chgrp users /srv/nfs
chmod g+w /srv/nfs
Make sure that your user name and user ID is known on the client as well as on the server. Refer to Chapter 8, Managing Users with YaST for detailed instructions about how to create and manage user accounts.

Prepare the NFS server:

Start YaST as root.

Select Network Services+NFS Server (this module is not installed by default. If it is missing in YaST, install the package yast2-nfs-server).

Enable NFS services with Start.

Open the appropriate firewall port with Open Port in Firewall if you are using a firewall.

Export the directories:

Click Add directory and select /srv/nfs.

Set the export options to:

rw,root_squash,async
Repeat these steps, if you need to export more than one directory.

Apply your settings and leave YaST. Your NFS server is ready to use.

To manually start the NFS server, enter rcnfsserver start as root. To stop the server, enter rcnfsserver stop. By default, YaST takes care of starting this service at boot time.

To configure the client, proceed as follows:

Prepare the NFS client:

Start YaST as root.

Select Network Services+NFS Client.

Activate Open Port in Firewall if using a firewall.

Import the remote file system:

Click Add.

Enter the name or IP address of the NFS server or click Choose to automatically scan the network for NFS servers.

Enter the name of your remote file system or automatically choose it with Select.

Enter an appropriate mount point, for example /mnt. If you repeat this step with another exported file system, make sure you choose another mount point than /mnt.

Repeat these steps if you need to import more than one external directory.

Apply your settings and leave YaST. Your NFS client is ready to use.

To start the NFS client manually, enter rcnfs start.

For more details you can refer following link.
http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_113/opensuse-reference/cha.filetrans.html#sec.filetrans.share

Comment: NFS is also sharing files. To transfer them use `scp` or `ftp`